# list of php constants linked by operator in filter_var

Tags: php, arrays, flags, filter-var

I created a class named Sanitize.

I use the filter_var function to filter and sanitize data. I built the filter_var() third parameter from an array: $options which is like the following code:

`private $options = array('typeOfData' => array('options' => array(), 'flags' => array()));`

I can build an array with the right options, but this method won't work. I wanted only one of either option or flag, it wouldn't be a problem. Unfortunately, I'd like to pass several option or flag constants to filter_var.

For the flags, is it possible to build the wanted result like FLAG1 | FLAG2?
If not, should I use filter_var, with a switch to use filter_var depending on the required flags?

This is the current code using filter_var: `filter_var($value, $this->filters[$typeOFData], $this->currentOptions);`

Comment: $options is an optional parameter inside one of your classes methods? Correct? What do you want passed to options? and what are you looking to filter out?

Comment: corrected parameter to third one of `filter_var()`, not of the function. Adding: the `filter_var()` use in my code.

Comment: Do you want to filter the same string a few different times using different flags? or is it that you want to filter with different flags depending on the instance? Both ways are easy.

Comment: I'd like to filter depending on the input type (gettype()) and on the oflags. For example: SANITIZE_FLOAT with no flag, or with  FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION, or with more options.

Answer (score 1):

A class that Sanitizes based on type:

```
class Sanitize{
private $data;
private $filteredData;
private $options;
private $typeof;
private $filters;

function __contruct($data){

$this->typeof = gettype($data);
$this->data = $data;

switch ($this->typeof){
    case "integer":
       $this->options = array( /* array of options for integer type*/ );
       $this->filters = array( /*array of all filters you want to use on integers*/ )
        break;
    case "string":
       //....
}

private function getSanitized(){

$filtersNum = count($this->filters);

for($x=0;$x<$filtersNum;$x++){

if(allowsOptions($this->filters[$x])){ $options = $this->options; }else{$options = null;}

$this->filteredData = filter_var($this->data, $this->filters[$x], $options)
}
}

private function allowsOptions($filter){
/* all your code to check*/
return true or false
}
}
```

I hope this helps, If not, let me know.

Comment: It's great but the basis of your class is similar to mine. The problem is not with one filter constant flag, like `array('flag' => FLAG)`, it's when I want to put more than one flag: `array('flag' => flag1 | flag2).

Comment: I revised it a little. Once you have all your filters set for all types, you then write a method. Have the method loop through the filters array. Understand?

Comment: It works. But the problem I have is that I'd like to have multiple flags, not just one and I don't see how i can do that.